# What Certificate for signing an Ionic (Cordova) Windows 10 UWP application?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, uwp, visual-studio-cordova

I have an Ionic application, which is currently deployed to the Apple and Android stores. I Now wish to deploy to the Windows store. I have Visual Studio 2015 and have built running the Ionic CLI. I see a lot of created files, including a `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.43_x86.appx`

For `iOS`, the signing is handled via the xcode / developers console, and for Android I created using the `keytool` which is part of the `JDK`. Now for Windows..

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/certificates) on certificates, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool) on signing.

I just want to see if I have this understanding correct before I do anything.... so unlike the iOS and Android, where I can just sign, with no extra cost, for the UWP, you actually need to **purchase** a certificate, just like you do for SSL,  to use for the signing of a UWP? Also the app uses SSL (makes `https` calls to a server via SSL) - not sure if this makes any difference to the certificate required (as when I ran in debug, the `https` call seemed to be blocked).

Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to see if I have this understanding correct before I do anything.... so unlike the iOS and Android, where I can just sign, with no extra cost, for the UWP, you actually need to purchase a certificate, just like you do for SSL, to use for the signing of a UWP?

No, you don't need to purchase an certificate to publish your app to store. You only need to create a certificate for package signing, for details, please refer to [Create a certificate for package signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing). Then you can sign your app using `SignTool`, please refer to [Sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

After that, when you are submitting your app, you will need to have a developer account, which requires some monetary cost,

Comment: Yes I did see both these topics. But the certificate link only seems to discuss a **self signed certificate**, and has the statement *A self signed certificate is useful for testing your app before you're ready to publish it to the store*. All the rest makes sense, the signing, and the developer account I already have, it was just the certificate part that is not clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as the generated certificate works well with the Sign Tool, the signed app can be published to the store.