# Certificate to use for building a Cordova UWP application for the Store

Tags: cordova, ionic2, uwp

Very similar to a previous question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271001/what-certificate-for-signing-an-ionic-cordova-windows-10-uwp-application), regarding certificates for an Ionic 2 (Cordova) application, I have since discovered if you *associate* your application in Visual Studio, the store seems to give us a certificate (CordovaApp.Windows10_StoreKey.pfx).

Until now, to test, I have been using the following command to build test versions..

```
ionic cordova build windows --prod --release -- --arch=x86 --buildConfig windows_certificate\\build.config
```

and in the build.config I have been pointing to a certificate (a purchased company certificate we use elsewhere), I manually install this certificates onto  a test machine.

My question is, do I now use the `CordovaApp.Windows10_StoreKey.pfx` supplied by the store? And if so, how does this certificate get installed onto a users machine (or does this happen when the user downloads from the store)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I now use the CordovaApp.Windows10_StoreKey.pfx supplied by the store?

This certificate would be used to sign your app package.

> how does this certificate get installed onto a users machine (or does this happen when the user downloads from the store)

When you're installing the app from windows store, the certificate will be installed automatically.

Comment: OK, I've signed using this certificate, and it looks like the store has accepted it. Now just to test installing it from the store, but I assume as said the certificate will be installed.